# How to remove label from element using Clearcase Clearteam explorer, how to remove a version

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-remote-client

I wish to remove a label from an element that I added incorrectly. How can I do that using ClearTeam explorer?

Also, if I checkin a version of an element incorrectly, how do I remove that version using ClearTeam Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the version is possible but dangerous (right click on the version, select delete version)

It is akin to a [cleartool rmver](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_rmver.htm?pos=2) and you should rmver only if:

- it is the last version
- it has no label or baseline applied to it
- it has no hyperlink (merge/deliver/rebase red arrows)

---

Regarding label, if it is not possible from the ClearTeam explorer, you still can use: [`cleartool rmlabel`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_rmver.htm?pos=2)

> The `rmlabel` command removes one or more version labels from versions of elements.

```
cleartool rmlabel -ver /main/3 A_LABEL util.c
```